# How to bind AJAX-loaded form to 'ngModel' [close]

Tags: ajax, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Received http://examle.com/ajax/login.html:

```html
<form method="post" action="/login.html" name="formLogin" data-ng-model="formLogin" data-ng-submit="submitLogin($event)" novalidate="novalidate" >
   <input type="hidden" csrf="csrf" data-ng-model="formLogin.csrf" value="" name="LoginForm[csrf]">

   <input type="text" data-ng-minlength="2" data-ng-required data-ng-model="formLogin.email" placeholder="e-mail" autofocus="autofocus" name="LoginForm[email]"></div>
   <span class="error" ng-show="formLogin['LoginForm[email]'].$error.required">Required!</span>

   <input type="text" data-ng-minlength="2" data-ng-required data-ng-model="formLogin.password" placeholder="password" autofocus="autofocus" name="LoginForm[password]"></div>
   <span class="error" ng-show="formLogin['LoginForm[password]'].$error.required">Required!</span>

   <button ng-disabled="formLogin.submitted" name="login-button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">OK</button>
</form>
```

The directive code looks as below:

```js
app.directive('formLogin', function(){
   return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
          var inputs = element[0].querySelectorAll('input');
      }
   };
});
```

In a classic [example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form), if specify the name of the form, the form controller will be published into related scope, under this name. Is it possible to do for AJAX-loaded form, something like?
The problem is in the validation inputs after loading form.

Comment: angular is designed to load much of the html by ajax using any number of internal directives or from `templateUrl` in custom directives or routes. What method are you using to load this form?

Comment: @charlietfl All right,`templateUrl`. The problem is in the validation `inputs` after loading form.

Comment: suggest you don't use same model object as form name for fields. Docs don't call for `ng-model` on form, validation object is created from form name. By using same name for both objects will be creating a possible collision. really have no idea what your directive is intended for

Comment: @charlietfl I found a bug. I had to specify the controller for the modal window, that contains a form. Thanks;)